# RMS Speed derivation Integral

Tags: integrals-of-motion

I am looking for a good table of integral to use for a class, but I also need help solving an integral that leads to RMS SPEED of a gas particle. The integral is of the following form:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^4e^{-ax^2}dx$

I have omitted several constants and left the bare integral which is what I am interested in. If someone can explain how to solve this integral OR show me a table of integrals that can help derive the answer. I know what it evaluates to, but I mostly want to learn how to get to the derivation whether it be through a complete integration or through substitution methods and then using a table of integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you a neat little trick that will help you out in solving a number of complicated integrals. We have the integral,

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}x^4e^{-ax^2}\,dx$$

Now define another integral,

$$I_0(a)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\,dx$$

These two integrals are related, all you need to do is take derivative of $I_0$ with respect to $a$ twice. We will get,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{da^2}I_0(a)&=\frac{d^2}{da^2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}e^{-ax^2}\,dx\\
&=I(a)
\end{align}$$

What I did in the second last line, is called the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) popularized by Feynman. Anyways you should notice that solving $I_0$ is a lot easier than solving $I$. In fact it's the popular Gaussian integral whose solution can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-displaystyle-int_-infty-infty-e-ax-2-dx-1/answer/Sambit-Sarkar-11) albeit for a $(-\infty,\infty)$ limit. I leave it upto you to change the integration limits and take the derivative to get to the solution.

Also note that after taking the double derivative, this looks like a differential equation of second order. You can try playing around with that fact and see what else you can figure out.